# Proving $1 +\sqrt[3]{5-\sqrt2}$ is rational via the rational roots theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, irrational-numbers

> Find a polynomial that has $x = 1 +\sqrt[3]{5-\sqrt2}$ as a root, then use rational roots theorem to show that $x$ must be rational.

I came up with the polynomial $100,000,000,000x^2 = 640393215809$ but their GCD is only $1$, so it won't work for part 2.  Anyone help with an easier function.

Comment: This number is not rational.

Comment: How did you get that polynomial? And I am not sure that your $x$ is rational.

Comment: Perhaps you mean "integer-algebraic" ?

Comment: Expand the expression $[(x-1)^3 - 5]^2 = 2$ to find the polynomial.

Comment: What on earth led you to believe that $1 +\sqrt[3]{5-\sqrt2}$ was a root of $100,000,000,000x^2 = 640393215809$?

Comment: The rational root theorem might suggest that to be rational you would need $x \in \{23,1,-1,-23\}$.  It is not, as it is obviously strictly greater than $1$ and less then $3$

Comment: @Henry:  I find the possibilities to be $34,17,2,1$ and their negatives

Comment: @Kayy Wang Before $ \sqrt$ signs  assume both of $\pm $signs

Answer (score 2):

If $1 +\sqrt[3]{5-\sqrt2}$ were rational, then $\sqrt[3]{5-\sqrt2}$ would be rational, so its cube $5-\sqrt2$ would be rational. Which it isn't.

Comment: Simpler: RRT  $\,\Rightarrow\,\sqrt 2\in \Bbb Z,\,$ and it is much easier to prove $\sqrt 2$ is nonintegral (vs. irrational) - see my answer. Note OP is supposed to use RRT, but your answer does not (though RRT can be used to prove $\sqrt 2$ is irrational).

Answer (score 1):

How about 
$$x=1+\sqrt[3]{5-\sqrt 2}\\
x-1=\sqrt[3]{5-\sqrt 2}\\
(x-1)^3=5-\sqrt 2\\
\sqrt 2=5-(x-1)^3\\
2=\left(5-(x-1)^3\right)^2\\
0 = x^6 - 6 x^5 + 15 x^4 - 30 x^3 + 45 x^2 - 36 x + 34$$
but I don't think your number is rational.  [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%3D(5-(x-1)%5E3)%5E2) does not find it to be.  I suspect the problem is to prove your number is irrational by the rational root theorem by finding all the possible rational roots of this equation and noting that your number is none of them.

Answer (score 1):

I got the minimal polynomial of your number to be $$ 34 - 36X + 45X^2 - 30X^3 + 15X^4 - 6X^5 + X^6\,, $$ which is not zero at $\pm1,\pm2\pm17$ or $\pm34$, so your number is irrational.

Comment: Easier to show $\sqrt 2\not\in\Bbb Z$ than to check all those possibilities - see my answer. RRT doesn't prove *irreducibility* - only the lack of linear factors.

Comment: Whoops, @BillDubuque, of course it doesn’t prove irreducibility, shame on me. I’ll correct.

Answer (score 1):

$((x\!-\!1)^{\large 3}\!-\!5)^{\large 2} =  \color{#c00}2\,$  so if $\,x\in\Bbb Q,\,$ RRT $\,\Rightarrow\,x\in \Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\,\sqrt{\color{#c00}2}\in\Bbb Z,\,$ contradiction, so $\,x\not\in\Bbb Q$

Comment: Though it's easier directly, we could also use RRT to prove $\,\sqrt{\color{#c00}2}\not\in\Bbb Z,\,$ since RRT implies the only possible integer roots of  $\,X^2-\color{#c00}2\,$ are $\,X = \pm1,\pm2,\,$ but none are roots